# React Native Development Server Error 500

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, npm, node-modules

Hey I'm trying to make my first app in react-native and I am running into an issue after trying to install react-navigation and react-navigation stack.

When i try to run react-native start I get this error:

```
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░ 57.2% (431/570)::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2020:23:06:17 +0000] "GET /index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `@react-native-community/masked-view` from `node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/module/vendor/views/MaskedView.native.js`: @react-native-community/masked-view could not be found within the project.
```

but I have react-native-community in my node modules folder and have tried installing it again but it doesn't seem to exist when i do npm install react-native-community.

Also I'm not sure if this is related but when i do react-native run-android It gets stuck at 99% now on the app:installDebug step.

Edit: Fixed needed to do npm install @react-native-community/masked-view

[image: Error on emulator]

Comment: Can u share your package.json file?

Answer (score 12):

install this in your project

*expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view*

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

Comment: yes it works... thanks a lot and God bless react native for these breakpoints upgrades :|

Comment: This is the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Run `npm list` in your working folder to see all dependencies in your project folder and look out for `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY`, then install all dependencies that are unmet

Answer (score 1):

"@react-native-community/masked-view" this dependence making error. I think so your using react-native-navigation which is making issue because in latest react-native(Version> 0.60)  this issues is occurring, but Version<0.60 lower than, working fine. So please down grade your react-native version after that this issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error

```
Unable to resolve "@react-native-community/masked-view" from "node_modules\react-navigation-stack\lib\module\vendor\views\MaskedView.native.js
```

Run `npm install @react-native-community/masked-view`